# Javascript remove spaces in the beginning of every line from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="post">
        # Heading 1
        Text

        ## Heading 2
        More text
    </div>
</body>
```

If I use `document.getElementById("post").innerHTML` on this, it will return:

```
"
        # Heading 1
        Text

        ## Heading 2
        More text
    "
```

How can I remove all these spaces in the beginning so it's like:

```
"# Heading 1
Text

## Heading 2
More text"
```

Thanks

Comment: Try getting `innerText` instead. It should do the work

Comment: As @VivekMolkar suggested, using `document.getElementById("post").innerText` will give you the trimmed content

Comment: This removes all the new lines and it's all in one single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [String.prototype.trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove extra spaces.

then you can split string by new line and then remove extra spaces with map method and at the end join lines again.

```js
const post = document.getElementById("post");
const parsedPost = post.innerHTML.trim().split("\n").map(line => line.trim()).join("\n");
console.log(parsedPost)
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="post">
        # Heading 1
        Text

        ## Heading 2
        More text
    </div>
</body>
```